How to aggragate data based on a keyword
I want to use Google Sheet as a time tracker. That is, in a cell I will write:
keyword_A 13:00-14:12

keyword_A is one keyword, among many, separated by space and then the starting time of the activity separated by a dash from the end time.
I want to be able designate a particular cell for the total time spent on activity keyword_A in a week, in a month, or total time spent so far.
How can I achieve this?

Please [edit] the question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Use split() and query(), like this:
=query( 
  filter(iferror(split(A2:A, " -"), 0), len(A2:A)), 
  "select Col1, sum(Col3) - sum(Col2) 
   where Col1 is not null 
   group by Col1 
   label Col1 'keyword', sum(Col3) - sum(Col2) 'duration' 
   format sum(Col3) - sum(Col2) '[h]:mm' ", 
  0 
)

The formula assumes that the values are in column A2:A.
See
filter(),
iferror(),
split() and
query().
